# Rails partial gets double escaped when using link_to_function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototype

I have the following code.

```
   def add_resume_link(name, form)
     link_to_function name do |page|
       html = form.fields_for :resumes, @general_resume.resumes.build, :child_index => 'NEW_RECORD' do |form_parent|
               render :partial => 'resume_form', :locals=>{:form=>form_parent} 
            end
       page << "$('resumes').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, id) });"
      end
    end
```

And on the `resume_form` i have somewhere:

```
 =add_skill_link("Add Skill", form, "resume_#{id}_skills")
```

and the function looks like:

```
  def add_skill_link(name, form, id)
    link_to_function name do |page|
      html = form.fields_for :skill_items, @general_resume.skill_items.build, :child_index => 'NEW_RECORD' do |form_parent|
        render :partial=>'skill_form', :locals=>{:form=>form_parent, :parent=>id}
      end
      page << "$('#{id}').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new Date().getTime()) });"
    end
  end
```

So basically i have a javascript code which dynamically adds a piece of html (`add_resume`) and contains another javascript code which dynamically adds a select box to the page.

My problem is that the `add_skill_link` works fine if i use from the server side, i mean rendering from server side. And gets double escaped when using within the upper described way.

I tried to remove the `escape_javascript` from the `add_skill_link` bit still not good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that things get too messy, finally I got my solution from Ryan Bates example application, he has a railscast about nested models, and there I browsed the branches and i got a branch with a nice clean solution to this problem. [link text](http://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/deep)

Answer (score 1):

Is this HAML?

```
=add_skill_link("Add Skill", form, "resume_#{id}_skills")
```

If so, you need to prevent HAML from escaping your output:

```
!=add_skill_link("Add Skill", form, "resume_#{id}_skills")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally I changed the whole thing, probably you're right, but i don't know if this solves my problem.